# Git operations on repository without a working tree?

Tags: git

The build workflow of a legacy project should checkout a specific git version tag and compile that sources.
I proposed to keep it simple and use Git Cli like that:

```
git clone –b $versiontag –singlebranch $gitrepouri
```

instead of git clone and git checkout tag afterwards.

To "save time", a colleague wants to use another approach = copy the .git folder from an existing Git repository at another server
to the build working dir and afterwards operate on that folder.

At first she tried with `git checkout $versiontag` after the copy.
The output has multiple entries like:

```
$ git checkout tags/sometag
D       Foobar/somefile
D       Foobar/someotherfile
[...]
Note: checking out 'tags/sometag'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state.
[...]
```

but the working tree content differs from a normal git clone and git checkout, though both suppose to be in
the detached head state and have checked out that specific tag.
Also there were problems with tools like Sonarqube, because git blame didn't work
(Missing blame information..).

Afterwards she tried with `git sparse-checkout` after the copy, and that seems to work
at first sight -
though it's much more complicated and complex compared to the simple Git Cli approach.

What are the drawbacks of using Git commands against a Git repository without working tree overall ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem, but could clone with `--no-checkout` argument help you?

Comment: @max630 --no--checkout is for partial clone as far as i understand. In fact  my question is, is it possible to use git commands on a git repository without a working tree and what are the drawbacks / problems if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git has an internal setting to *tell* itself that it's using a clone with no work-tree.  Specifically, `core.bare` should be set to `true` for such a repository.

Copying a repository manually, rather than using `git clone` to copy it, copies its configuration files (`.git/config` and `.git/info/` files).  This includes the `core.bare` setting *and* several settings that Git creates on its own to describe the behavior of the machine and file-system on which Git is running.  If these settings do not reflect the actual machine and actual file system, things may go wrong in various ways.  Some of the `info` files may point Git into additional directories *not* copied; if so, you need to know what to do about these as well.  So, unless you know what you are doing with respect to these other variables and `info` files, do not use `cp -r` (or `tar` or similar) to copy the `.git` directory directly.

Copying the raw `.git` repository also copies the index for that repository.  The index describes the work-tree, so the copied index is automatically incorrect if the new location has no work-tree.  (Note: all repositories, including bare ones, have an index.  The index for an initially-bare repository is normally empty, but see below.)

That said, you *can* do *some* Git operations on a bare repository.  Specifically, you can do any operation that does not require a work-tree.  This means that if you know what you are doing with respect to the special control variables, you *can* copy a `.git` repository elsewhere and then use it.  Since you will be avoiding operations that use the work-tree—which means avoiding `git checkout`, for instance—the broken index is not a problem, although if you're going to be this clever, which is perhaps too clever by half, you can also just know when it is safe to *remove* the broken index.

You can also supply a temporary work-tree for a bare repository, using `git --work-tree=<path> ...` or `GIT_WORK_TREE=<path> git ...`.  If you do this, that overrides the `core.bare` setting, and the bare repository's index is used to keep track of the given `<path>`.  Note that if you change paths, you invalidate the index; in this case, you must either use another index (by setting `GIT_INDEX_FILE` to an alternate index) or remove the existing index.

So, with all the above caveats in mind, you *can* convert a `.git` directory to a proper bare Git repository, or use `cp` or `tar` to transplant a `.git` directory including or excluding its current work-tree to a new location with a new work-tree.  But in general, you *shouldn't*, because if you do this, you must make a lot of assumptions about future versions of Git.  Git promises that `git clone` and `git bundle` and the like will keep working the way it does now; Git does not promise that sneaky surgery on a copied `.git` directory will keep working this same way.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer!